# Compare Two tables in SQL and equals row set to 'True' in new Column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, datatable, equals

Can some one explain the **SQL** query for bellow outcomes in TableResult.

```
TableA                        TableB                    TableResult

Id | Function                 Id | Function              Id | Function | Compare
---|----------               ----|----------            ----|----------|---------
1  | code1                    1  | code1                 1  | code1    | true
2  | code2                    2  | code4                 2  | code2    | false
3  | code3                    3  | code5                 3  | code3    | false
4  | code4                                               4  | code4    | true
```

There is two tables **TableA** and **TableB**, Function column in both tables are unique.
Entire data in TableA should be there in ResultTable, If TableB Function equals in TableA function, Then **ResultTable Compare** column must be true otherwise it's false.

Can anyone advised How to get the desired outcome in SQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select a.*,
  exists (select 1 from TableB b where b.function = a.function) compare
from TableA a
```

or:

```
select a.*,
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from TableB b where b.function = a.function) then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end compare
from TableA a
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb38be69ff056c114d480efad1f1cc09).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and test whether there was a match.

```
SELECT a.*, IF(b.id IS NULL, 'false', 'true') AS compare
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON a.function = b.function
```